# Data frame - adding index with count of values under each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Region': ['E', 'E', 'U', 'E'], 'Id': [1,None,None,None], 'Ids': [1,2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Region': ['E', 'U', 'U', 'E'], 'Id': [1,2,3,4], 'Ids': [1,2,3,4]})
x = df1.groupby(['Region']).count()
y = df2.groupby(['Region']).count()


c = pd.concat([x['Id'], y['Id']], axis=1, keys=['Here', 'There'])
```

I have the table with two rows (like indices, 'E' and 'U') which count the number of E and U for each data frame and concatenate them with different keys: Here and There.
Now I want to add another index, let's call it 'Total' and next to it I want get the total number of values under 'Here' and 'There'.

Now:

| Region | Here | There |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E | 1 | 2 |
| U | 0 | 2 |

Now I want to add another index, let's call it 'Total' and next to it I want get the total number of values under 'Here' and 'There'.

I want to achieve:

| Region | Here | There |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E | 1 | 2 |
| U | 0 | 2 |
| Total | 1 | 4 |

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it simply by defining it as the `sum`:

```
c.loc['Total'] = c.sum()
```

Output:

```
        Here  There
Region             
E        1.0    2.0
U        0.0    2.0
Total    1.0    4.0
```

Comment: @Jezrael Thanks for the quick edit :) - Rustam feel free to accept the answer if this solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
c.loc['total'] = c.sum(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
    Here    There
Region      
E   1   2
U   0   2
total   1   4
```

Comment: @RustamKarimov if it's good mark it as accepted